# Prove tower property of conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]| Y = y] = \mathbb{E}[X|Y = y]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am using Sheldon Ross 9th edition as a reference and all I am given is the definition of conditional expectation:

$$E[X|Y = y] = \sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y]$$

I am required to prove the tower property of conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]| Y = y] = \mathbb{E}[X|Y = y]$$

I am very lost and need assistance. First, we recognize that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]$ is a random variable that is a function of $Y,W$

We first write:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y,W=w] =  \sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y,W = w],$$

then,

\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]| Y = y] &= \mathbb{E}[\sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y,W = w]|Y = y]\\ &= \sum\limits_y \sum\limits_w \sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y,W = w] yw\Pr[Y = y,W = w|Y = y]\\ & = \sum\limits_y \sum\limits_w \sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y,W = w] yw\frac{\Pr[Y = y,W = w]}{\Pr[Y=y]} \\ &= \sum\limits_y \sum\limits_w \sum\limits_x x  yw\frac{\Pr[X = x,Y=y,W=w]}{\Pr[Y=y]} \end{align*}

The problem is at this stem, all I get is: $\dfrac{1}{\Pr[Y=y]}$.

I strongly suspect:

\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]| Y = y] = \sum\limits_y \sum\limits_w \sum\limits_x x \Pr[X = x| Y = y,W = w] yw\Pr[Y = y,W = w|Y = y] \end{align*} is incorrect. But it makes intuitive sense to me. We are taking the expectation of two jointly defined random variables $Y,W$, so the probability is $\Pr[Y = y,W = w|Y = y]$.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: In the first equation after "then", what you are writing in the RHS is not $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y,W]| Y = y]$$ but $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y,W=w]| Y = y]=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y,W=w]$$ Recall that each $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y,W=w]$$ is simply a *number*, not a random variable.

Comment: Perhaps more at the heart of your problem, you seem to have a definition of $E(X\mid Y=y)$ and $E(X\mid Y=y,W=w)$ at your disposal, but not of $E(X\mid Y,W)$. Is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've adapted the following definition of $\mathbb E [X \vert W, Y]$ from the discussion in Probability with Martingales by Williams, section 9.6.

Define the function $g$ by

$$g (w,y) = \mathbb E[X \vert W = w, Y = y]. $$

We define $\mathbb E [X \vert W,Y]$ to be the *random variable* $g(W,Y)$. Note this is different from the expectation of $X$ conditional on the event $\{W=W, Y=Y\}$, which is clearly the unconditional expectation of $X$.

We can thus make the following calculation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [ \mathbb E [X \vert W,Y] \vert Y= y ] &= \mathbb E [g(W,Y) \vert Y = y] \\
&= \sum_{w,y^\prime} g\left(w,y^\prime \right) \Pr \left[\left.W = w, Y = y^\prime \right\vert Y = y\right] \\
&= \sum_w g(w,y) \Pr [W = w \vert Y = y] \\
&= \sum_w \mathbb E [X \vert W=w,Y=y] \Pr [W = w \vert Y = y] \\
&= \sum_w \left[ \sum_x x \Pr [X=x \vert W=w,Y=y] \right]\Pr [W = w \vert Y = y] \\
&= \sum_{w,x} x \Pr[X=x, W=w \vert Y = y] \\
&= \sum_x x \Pr[X = x \vert Y = y] \\
&= \mathbb E[X \vert Y=y]
\end{align*}

The third equality follows from the fact that $\Pr \left[\left.W = w, Y = y^\prime \right\vert Y = y\right]$ is $\Pr[W = w \vert Y= y]$ for $y^\prime = y$ and $0$ otherwise. The sixth equality comes from Bayes' rule. The rest should follow from definitions.

Comment: Why the first identity? This seems to identify $$\mathbb E [X \vert W,Y]$$ with $$  \sum_x x \Pr [X=x \vert W, Y=y ]$$ which is wrong. If this is appealing to another property of conditional expectation, it seems mandatory to explain this property.

Comment: @Did thanks for the comment. I’ve edited my answer. Is that better, or does it need more detail?

Comment: Actually, my second comment on main seems to apply here as well: do you have a *definition* of $E(X\mid Y,W)$ at hand?

Comment: @Did Yes. It is the random variable $Z$ (measurable wrt $\sigma(W,Y)$) that satisfies $E \left[ \mathbb I_A Z \right] = E\left[ \mathbb I_A X \right]$ for every $A \in \sigma(W,Y)$. Employing this particular definition does not seem helpful here, at least in terms of answering the OP. Do you have a more useful suggestion?

Comment: Sorry but how can one solve this question without relying on a definition of $E(X\mid Y,W)$? If you are using another definition, once again, please provide it. To sum up, my suggestion would be to start from a definition of $E(X\mid Y,W)$ to solve the exercise (preferably the one in your comment or an equivalent form), rather than shoehorning without justification an identity basically equivalent to the conclusion in an early step of the proof.

Comment: @Did yes, of course one needs a definition for $E[X \mid W,Y]$. I did not claim that one was unnecessary or useless. To clarify, I was asking if you had an alternative definition that might be more suited for the simpler discrete setting than the one in my previous comment.

Comment: I doubt there is one.

Comment: @Did I've tried to work with a simpler definition for this setting, as edited above. I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on it.

Comment: The new version is sound. Bravo! (I corrected a small typo.)