# Clearing up a certain confusion about conditional expectation of the form $\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)|Y = y]$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Given $X,Y$ random variables, I want to find the explicit expression of

$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)|Y = y]$$

I always think of this question like this:

Define a new function $f(X,Y) = h(X)g(Y)$,

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|Y = y] = \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_y f(x,y) \Pr[X = x,Y = y|Y = y]$$

$$\implies \mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)|Y = y] = \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_y h(x)g(y) \Pr[X = x,Y = y|Y = y]$$

(perhaps I am thinking of the case of the un-conditioned expectation over two random variables)

However, the correct answer is:

$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)|Y = y] = \sum\limits_x h(x)g(y) \Pr[X = x,Y = y|Y = y]$$

(alternatively: $\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)|Y = y] = \sum\limits_x h(x)g(y) \Pr[X = x|Y = y]$)

I have an intuitive feeling as to why the correct answer does not sum over $y$, however, I cannot express it. I want to say something like: since $Y$ is given, therefore $Y$ is no longer a random variable, hence $X$ is the only random variable, and therefore the average is summed over the values of $X$ only. It doesn't feel correct because $Y$ is still a random variable.

Can someone clear this up for me and offer a reason why we do not sum over $y$?

Following this logic, would the following expressions also be correct?

$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)l(z)|Z = z] = \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_y h(x)g(y)l(z) \Pr[X = x,Y = y, Z = z|Z = z]$$

or

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[h(X)|Y, Z]|Z = z] = \sum\limits_y \sum\limits_x h(x) \Pr[X = x|Y = y, Z = z]\Pr[Y=y, Z = z|Z = z]$$

Comment: $E[h(X) g(Y)|Y=y]= g(y) E[h(X) |Y=y]$ This is  basic property. See wikipedia page on conditional expectation.

Comment: @Lisa I know the solution, my question is why don't we sum over $y$ in the conditional expectation? Aren't we dealing with joint density?

Comment: We are dealing with conditional entropy $E[h(X)g(Y)|Y=y]= \int h(x) g(y) dP(X|y=y)$   on in the discrete case  $E[h(X)g(Y)|Y=y]=\sum_{x_i} h(x) g(y) p_{X|Y}(x_i|y)$

Comment: @Lisa I think you are given those definitions. How would you express more complicated cases such as $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y,Z)|Z =z]$?

Comment: $E[X|Y,Z]$ is just a function of $(Y,Z)$.So,  $E[ E[X|Y,Z] |Z=z]= \sum_{y_i} E[X|Y=y,Z=z]  P_{Y|Z}(y_i|z)$. Moreover, by towering property we have that  $E[ E[X|Y,Z] |Z=z]=E[X |Z=z]$

Comment: @Lisa You said $E[X|Y,Z]$ is a function of $(Y,Z)$, so shouldn't the expectation be evaluated only their joint density instead, and what made you decide to only sum over $y$ instead of $y$ and $z$?

Comment: The outer conditional expectation should be evaluated with respect to $P_{Y|Z}$. This by definition.

Comment: What could the sum over $y$ in the RHS even **mean** knowing that $y$ appears in the LHS?

Comment: [Connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2610172/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone clear this up for me and offer a reason why we do not sum over $y$?

Because the expectation is under the condition that $Y=y$, where $y$ is a *singular* value .

If you sum over just one value, what are you doing?

Would it help to use a different symbol for the condition value?

$$\mathsf E(g(X)h(Y)\mid Y=c) ~{= \sum_{x}\sum_y g(x)h(y)\Pr(X=x,Y=y\mid Y=c) \\ = \sum_x g(x)h(c)\Pr(X=x\mid Y=c) \\ = \mathsf E(g(X)\mid Y=c) \;h(c)}$$

Since $\Pr(X=x, Y=y\mid Y=c) = \begin{cases}\Pr(X=x\mid Y=c)&:& y=c\\ 0 &:& y\neq c\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks for the clear up, I just have one more question. Suppose that $Y$ is a discrete random variable that takes on the values from $1$ to $k$, including some integer value $c$ in between $1$ and $k$.

Comment: Then from your first line, expanding out the sum, we have: $\mathsf E(g(X)h(Y)\mid Y=c) = \sum_{x}\sum_y g(x)h(y)\Pr(X=x,Y=y\mid Y=c) =\sum_{x} g(x) (h(1) + \ldots + h(c) + \ldots + h(k)) \Pr(X=x,Y=y\mid Y=c) = \sum_{x} g(x) (h(1) + \ldots + h(c) + \ldots + h(k)) \Pr(X=x,Y=y, Y=c)/\Pr(Y = c)  = \sum_{x} g(x) (h(1) + \ldots + h(c) + \ldots + h(k)) \Pr(X=x,Y=c)/\Pr(Y = c)  = \sum_{x} g(x) (h(1) + \ldots + h(c) + \ldots + h(k)) \Pr(X=x\mid Y = c)$ The problems is that the other terms in the summation has not gone away. Can you explain this?

Comment: The other terms do vanish because the expansion is: $${{\sum_x\sum_y g(x)h(y)\Pr(X=x,Y=x\mid Y=c) }\\{ = \sum_x g(x)\,[h(1)\cdotp0+h(2)\cdotp0+...+h(c)\,\Pr(X=x\mid Y=c)+\ldots+h(k)\cdotp0]\\ = \sum_x g(x)\,h(c)\,\Pr(X=x\mid Y=c)}}$$

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation. A lot of intricacies hiding in between the lines